# mIRC how to repeat string with white spaces in between?

Tags: string, mirc

How to repeat a string adding a white space in between ? `$str(ho, 3)` will return `hohoho` and I want `ho ho ho`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `$chr` identifier.

```
$str(ho $chr(32), 3)
```

Comment: it's working thanks can you help me with my other problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33861748/script-to-generate-random-string-not-working